# How to convert string to xml in jquery version 1.3 and below ? How to add node to xml?

Tags: jquery, xml

I am taking xml string from hidden field and i need to add node to this xml. So to add new node first i need to convert xml string to xml object but i am using jquery version 1.3 i can't use parseXML() method.

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to use `parseXml` by copying it from a version that includes it in the core. Following is copied from version 1.11.2

```
// Cross-browser xml parsing
jQuery.parseXML = function( data ) {
    var xml, tmp;
    if ( !data || typeof data !== "string" ) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
            tmp = new DOMParser();
            xml = tmp.parseFromString( data, "text/xml" );
        } else { // IE
            xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
            xml.async = "false";
            xml.loadXML( data );
        }
    } catch( e ) {
        xml = undefined;
    }
    if ( !xml || !xml.documentElement || xml.getElementsByTagName( "parsererror" ).length ) {
        jQuery.error( "Invalid XML: " + data );
    }
    return xml;
};


// use it here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to parse your XML data like,

```
var txt=document.getElementById('hiddenId').value;
if (window.DOMParser){
    parser=new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
} else // Internet Explorer
{
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt);
}
```

Also if you see the latest versions for [$.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml) then the code for it looks like,

```
// you can extend jquery and use the below function, also
// copied from jquery 1.7.0 minified version
parseXML: function (c) {
       var d,
       f;
       try {
            a.DOMParser ? (f = new DOMParser, d = f.parseFromString(c, 'text/xml'))  : (d = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'), d.async = 'false', d.loadXML(c))
       } catch (g) {
            d = b
       }(!d || !d.documentElement || d.getElementsByTagName('parsererror').length) && e.error('Invalid XML: ' + c);
          return d
 },
```

Answer (score 0):

If your current version of jQuery doesn't support `$.parseXML()`, you could drop [the `$.parseXML()` implementation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery/ef6d8779de9d5959eafc0b9706b90a585aaf7a26/src/core.js) into your code (below is a somewhat old version of the implementation from before they limited its IE support to IE9+):

```
jQuery.parseXML = jQuery.parseXML || function( data ) {
    var xml, tmp;
    if ( !data || typeof data !== "string" ) {
        return null;
    }
    try {
        if ( window.DOMParser ) { // Standard
            tmp = new DOMParser();
            xml = tmp.parseFromString( data , "text/xml" );
        } else { // IE
            xml = new ActiveXObject( "Microsoft.XMLDOM" );
            xml.async = "false";
            xml.loadXML( data );
        }
    } catch( e ) {
        xml = undefined;
    }
    if ( !xml || !xml.documentElement || xml.getElementsByTagName( "parsererror" ).length ) {
        jQuery.error( "Invalid XML: " + data );
    }
    return xml;
};
```

Then use it as normal:

```
var x = $($.parseXML("<a><b></b></a>"));
x.find("b").text("hello!");
```